# Calculate new RGB Values with current RGB Values and brightness

Tags: python, rgb

My goal is to read out the current RGB values of my device (this part works) and calculating the new RGB values with a brightness value. The brightness value comes via mqtt and is between 0 and 255, RGB values also range from 0 to 255. Currently, I get no usable RGB values, like 100023 and so. \n
My code works with callbacks, each callback is setup for multiple devices. I have one callback with if statement, which checks for the payload and executes each case, like `state = 0` or `color = [245, 0, 30]`
My first idea was calculating a value called fac by mapping the range from 0 to 255 to the range of 0 and 100 and mulitplying each RGb value with the fac, but that gives the unusable output. In the current code ive added a bit math to get usable values, but i have some thought errors in it
Some minimal code:

```
 elif 'brightness' in payload: #brightness changed
            print(f"brightness changed: {payload['brightness']}")
            color = {}
            led_info = sdk.get_led_positions_by_device_index(device_index)
            current_color = sdk.get_led_colors_by_device_index(device_index, list(led_info))
            current_color2 = tuple(current_color.values())
            print(f"nwo current color is: {current_color2}")
            current_color3 = current_color2[1]
            print(type(current_color3))
            print(current_color3)
            fac = payload['brightness']
            print(fac)
            color['r'] = math.floor(current_color3[0] / fac)
            color['g'] = math.floor(current_color3[1] / fac)   
            color['b'] = math.floor(current_color3[2] / fac)
            set_all_device_leds(device_index, color)
            state_payload["state"] = "ON"
            state_payload["brightness"] = payload["brightness"]
            state_payload["color"] = color
            print(state_payload["color"])
```

For a view of my full sources (if needed), heres the github link: https://github.com/Tenn0/iCue2sACN/blob/67ab0a52eeb127d98c768228f7015326323a4a1c/src/main.py
(the function is at line 177)

Comment: Have you tried to use the `fac` value as a percentage? You could simply multiply the values and calculate their ratio. Anyway, check [this question on SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/75419), maybe it can be helpful

Comment: TBH, i dont know how to use the fac as percentage. in C++ there was map() which mapped my range from 0 to 255 (input) to percentages easily, but i havent found anything related in python

Comment: I don't understand if I get it properly, but for what you asked, I meant to use `fac` as a percentage, e.g,, `fac` value would be in a range from 0 to 1 and you could obtain the new value, as you tried to do: `color['r'] = math.floor(current_color3[0] * fac)`. Anyway the question I linked to you should cover how to manipulate colors and percentage brightness

Comment: yeah, i got the part to use fac as percentage. but how can i optain the fac as percentage? my input for brightness comes as value from 0 to 255

Comment: You could just divide it by 255; in fact, you would have a variable with a value between 0 and 1. E.g. `percentage = fac / 255`

Comment: i found my solution: the map() function i mentioned was not in c++, it was implemented in arduino. luckily, they provided the whole code of the function, which i just copied and that works

Comment: So, let me get that straight: you didn't want to know how to obtain an rgb value modified by a brightness level, but only how to map it? I just am really confused by this `map()` function you're continuing to mention and what cpp or arduino have to do with it. Anyway, glad that works now